# How can I dynamically fill a dropdown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I fetch employee id from my database and display it. Now I need to fill a dropdown value in a table dynamically, once I click `addRow()`, but it doesn't show any value in the dropdown. What's the error? Please help me to complete this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onClick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<table id="dataTable"></table>
```

```js
function addRow() {
  var option = '';
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($employee);?>;
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    option += '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.id + '</option>';
  });
  $('#emp_id').append(option);

  $("#dataTable").append('<tr><td><select name="emp_id" id="emp_id"></select</td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: php data variable shows the employee id and there is no error in console

Comment: because of useless minus votes, people are not giving answers on stackoverflow!!

Comment: @BhumiShah the downvotes on your answer were more than deserved. It didn't address the problem at all and instead simply introduced syntax errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossanP: That doesn't meant to downvote!! People can comment to change it to comment!! This way people are ignoring stackoverflow to help!! I was helping and my free work was get negative impact!! great

Comment: That's *exactly* what downvotes are for. Your 'free work' had a negative impact by giving bad guidance to the OP and potentially wasting their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attempting to add the `option` elements to a `select` element you have not yet created in the DOM. To fix this create the `select` first, then add the `option` elements to it.

Also note that it would be better to assign a `class` to the new `select`, not an `id`, to avoid duplicates. You can also make the logic to create the `option` elements more succinct by using `map()` like this:

```js
function addRow() {
  var data = [{ id: 'foo' }, { id: 'bar' }]; // <?php echo json_encode($employee);?>;
  var options = data.map(function(el) {
    return `<option value="${el.id}">${el.id}</option>`;
  });
  var $tr = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').appendTo('#dataTable');
  $('<select name="emp_id" class="emp_id" />').html(options).appendTo($tr.find('td'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onClick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<table id="dataTable"></table>
```

Comment: If there are two more columns how can I append in table after this step.

Comment: You can just add those to the line which creates the `tr td` elements

Comment: In this select option how can I append default value like this ---select--- .

Comment: Add this line: `options = '<option value="">--- select ---</option>' + options;`